# How to use *ngIf Else with variable

Tags: angular, angular-directive

For example I want to define ng-template with the variable 
something like this

```
<ng-template
  #notExpandableIconRef
  let-variable="variable">
  <i class="far fa-edit mr-2 ml-1 pointer" (click)="onClick(variable)"></i>
</ng-template>
```

And I have a condition, and when the condition is false I need to show `notExpandableIconRef`
something like this

```
<i class="far fa-edit mr-2 ml-1 pointer" *ngIf="some condition; else notExpandableIconRef"></i>
```

but the problem is that I could not find a way to define a variable by using ngIfElse directiove,

Currently, I have resoled the problem in this way

```
<i class="far fa-edit mr-2 ml-1 pointer" *ngIf="some condition"></i>
<span *ngIf="!(some condition)">
   <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="notExpandableIconRef;context:{variable: someVariable}">. 
   </ng-container>
</span>
```

My question is: Is there a simple way to do this by ngIfElse directive?
for example something like this

```
<i class="far fa-edit mr-2 ml-1 pointer" *ngIf="some condition; else notExpandableIconRef; SomehowDefineTheVariable"></i>
```

here is the stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-app-example-mta5z6?file=src/app/app.component.html

Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about a variable similar to the one that can be defined for the `ngIf` part? What value do you expect the variable to have in the `ngIfElse` part?

Comment: Can you create a {stackblitz}(https://stackblitz.com/) with your code to help you?

Comment: I have created the stackblitz example

Comment: @ConnorsFan sorry I don't understand your question? can the Stackblitz example help you understand my question?

Comment: Why do you need to define a variable in the `ngIfElse` template? Why not use the class property directly? See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-app-example-azngzd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Comment: @ConnorsFan the problem is that this is a simple example for explain what I want, but the case when I need to use this is nested accordion data.

Comment: and when the level doesn't have child levels it should have another functionality, and in that case I need to use ng-template with the variable.